# yum install kmod-nvidia - kernel issue

Tags: centos, yum, nvidia

Impossible to install NVIDIA driver on CentOS release CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core), the package `kmod-nvidia` gives errors and kernel incompatibilities.

Usually installed with `yum install kmod-nvidia -y`

Current output:

```
sudo yum install kmod-nvidia Loaded plugins: nvidia Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kmod-nvidia.x86_64 0:384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nvidia-x11-drv = 384.59 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(reservation_object_add_excl_fence) = 0x0afefde4 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_vblank_init) = 0xd594e463 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_universal_plane_init) = 0x66bc7079 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_printk) = 0xf3207539 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_plane_cleanup) = 0x993b0648 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_object_property_set_value) = 0xda980fae for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_modeset_unlock_all) = 0x0e3b5f46 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_modeset_lock_all) = 0x4d82712c for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_validate_size) = 0x59f75768 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_set_name) = 0x68b96c96 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_prune_invalid) = 0x0be80b87 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_probed_add) = 0x3c7e12fa for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_object_find) = 0xcd45520d for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_create_dvi_i_properties) = 0x97b982aa for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_create) = 0x0a488c2e for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_connector_update_edid_property) = 0x85c884c2 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_connector_list_update) = 0xf719e9fa for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_connector_attach_encoder) = 0xc542c1b2 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_config_init) = 0xc62e5245 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_mode_config_cleanup) = 0x373bd683 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_kms_helper_poll_init) = 0xc584cf3b for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_kms_helper_poll_fini) = 0xb54dc905 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_kms_helper_poll_disable) = 0x486dd196 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_kms_helper_hotplug_event) = 0xba22491c for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_helper_mode_fill_fb_struct) = 0xb62aeac2 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_helper_hpd_irq_event) = 0xdef9ef66 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_gem_private_object_init) = 0xdfd2d95f for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd) = 0xec097b40 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_gem_prime_export) = 0x87fc4b9b for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_gem_object_unreference_unlocked) = 0xe40a4bd7 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_gem_object_unreference) = 0xdc0d14b6 for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(drm_gem_object_release) = 0xe2f2760b for package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64

...

Error: Package: kmod-nvidia-384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo.x86_64 (elrepo)
           Requires: kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xe20392ec
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.6.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.21.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0xb9ded30c
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 (base)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.6.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.21.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(drm_atomic_helper_set_config) = 0x0a284bbd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.x86_64
ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.7.noarch
```

Comment: same situation with kmod-hfsplus package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by checking the different versions available:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=elrepo --showduplicates list kmod-nvidia
Loaded plugins: nvidia
Available Packages
kmod-nvidia.x86_64 367.57-1.el7.elrepo elrepo
kmod-nvidia.x86_64 367.57-2.el7.elrepo elrepo
kmod-nvidia.x86_64 367.57-3.el7.elrepo elrepo
kmod-nvidia.x86_64 375.66-1.el7.elrepo elrepo
kmod-nvidia.x86_64 384.59-1.el7.elrepo elrepo
kmod-nvidia.x86_64 384.59-2.el7_4.elrepo elrepo
```

Then, install the correct version for the right release, CentOS is still in EL7_3:

```
sudo yum install kmod-nvidia-384.59-1.el7.elrepo -y
```